# TinyMCE is not preventing invalid elements

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

I'm using tinyMCE 4.3.2 and I’ve initliazed tinyMCE as mentioned below.

```
tinymce.init({
                    selector: '#modal-content .tinymce',
                    theme: 'modern',
                    external_plugins: {
                        'lists': '/assets/js/tinymce/plugins/lists/plugin.min.js',
                        'link': '/assets/js/tinymce/plugins/link/plugin.min.js',
                        'charmap': '/assets/js/tinymce/plugins/charmap/plugin.min.js',
                        'hr': '/assets/js/tinymce/plugins/hr/plugin.min.js',
                        'searchreplace': '/assets/js/tinymce/plugins/searchreplace/plugin.min.js',
                        'paste': '/assets/js/tinymce/plugins/paste/plugin.min.js',
                        'wordcount': '/assets/js/tinymce/plugins/wordcount/plugin.min.js',
                        'visualblocks': '/assets/js/tinymce/plugins/visualblocks/plugin.min.js',
                        'visualchars': '/assets/js/tinymce/plugins/visualchars/plugin.min.js',
                        'code': '/assets/js/tinymce/plugins/code/plugin.min.js',
                        'table': '/assets/js/tinymce/plugins/table/plugin.min.js',
                        'contextmenu': '/assets/js/tinymce/plugins/contextmenu/plugin.min.js'
                    },
                    toolbar1: "undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link code",
                    valid_elements: 'a[*],p[*],ul[*],li[*]',
                    invalid_elements: "script,object,embed,link,style,form,input,iframe",
                    relative_urls: true,
                    remove_script_host: true
                });
```

When I'm trying to take value in JavaScript , it is not preventing invalid elements. It is taking iframe ,script and all other invalid elements. But It is working fine in PHP when form is submitted And when I'm getting data in post.

I'm trying to take value of editor from below mentioned ways. But it is not working.

```
tinymce.triggerSave();
tinyMCE.get('editor').getContent({format : 'text'})
tinyMCE.get('editor').getContent({format : 'raw'})
```

I want way to prevent invalid elements before I send value to server through Ajax. Let me know if there is any best possible way to prevent invalid elements.

Comment: you can try to call tinyMCE.get('editor').triggerSave() right before you try to get the content - this might trigger the cleanup functionality of tinymce

Comment: Yes I've add tinymce.triggerSave(); before I take the value.

Comment: can you show use a live example of your implementation?

Comment: This is the live example. If there is invalid elements in text then it should strip as it is doing while posting data in php. But it is not prevent invalid elements and giving me the text as it is entered.

Comment: a live example can be found on a reachable web page - like a tinymce js fiddle (example: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/pnfaab)

Comment: Ok need to create that. Please give some time for that.

Comment: check example in this fiddle : http://fiddle.tinymce.com/qnfaab/2  , Just enter such text <iframe src="http://www.google.com"></iframe> and then press hitMe button , It will display all text.  It should be removed iframe and other invalid text from the entered text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing here is adding the string `'<iframe src="google.com"></iframe>'` to the editor content, but this is not a dom element and therefor won't get removed by tinymce. Everything is as it should be.

Comment: so you mean to say that I need to find html tags through javascript and prevent invalid elements manually that is the only way !

Comment: when you have your tags in string form and not as dom element in the editor then you will have to do it using string operations. btw, you are not able to insert iframe tags inside a tinymce editor as real dom elements because tinymce itself uses an own iframe with own head and body dom element to make you edit the content in the body dom element.

Comment: input and form elements can exist as dom elements in the tinymce editor (i am not sure about script tags), but you need to configure tinymce to treat them as valid elements and add them to the valid_children (of other nodes), otherwise tinymce will strip those elements from the dom

Comment: Can you give me an example for that ?

Comment: valid_elements: "@[id|class|title|style|onmouseover]," +
  "a[name|href|target|title|alt]," +
  "#p,blockquote,-ol,-ul,-li,br,img[src|height|width],-sub,-sup,-b,-i,-u," +
  "-span[data-mce-type],hr,script,input,form",
  
  valid_children: "body[p|ol|ul|script|input|form]" +
  ",p[a|span|b|i|u|sup|sub|img|hr|#text|script|input|form]" +
  ",span[p|a|b|i|u|sup|sub|img|#tex|script|input|formt]",